# pytorch: How does loss behave when coming from two networks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I am trying to implement [the following algorithm in this book, section 13.5](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), in pytorch.

[image]

This would require two separate neural networks, (in this question, `model1` and `model2`). One's loss is dependent only on its own output [via delta] (parameterized by w), the other (parameterized by theta), dependent both on its own output [via ln(pi)], and on the other's output [again, via delta].

**I want to update each one separately**

Assume the following models implement `nn.Module`:

```
model1 = Mynet1()
model2 = Mynet2()

val1 = model1(input1)
val2 = model2(input2)

self.optimizer1 = optim.Adam(model1.parameters(), lr1)
self.optimizer2 = optim.Adam(model2.parameters(), lr2)

loss1 = f(val1)
loss2 = f(val1, val2)#THIS IS THE INTERESTING PART

optim1.zero_grad()
loss1.backward
optim1.step()

optim2.zero_grad()
loss2.backward
optim2.step()
```

I understand that applying backward on loss1, then stepping its optimizer would update `model1`'s parameters.

My question is what happens when activating the same on `loss2`, `model2`, `optimizer2`, where **loss 2 is dependant on outputs both from `model1` and `model2`**?

How can I make the `loss2` update not affect `model1` parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `optim2` has only model2's parameter it will only update `model2` if you do `optim2.step()` as is being done.

However, `loss2.backward()` will compute gradients for both model1 and model2's params and if you do `optim1.step()` after that it will update model1's params. If you don't want to compute gradients for model1's param, you can do `val1.detach()` to detach it from the computational graph.

Comment: No, once detached it can't be attached. It is as if computational graph from which `val1` was computed is deleted

Comment: To clarify the above, `val1.detach()` *returns a new Tensor* which does not remember which steps were performed on it. The original `val1` will still have all that information. `detach()` does not modify the Tensor.

Comment: To add, you can do `val1.detach_()` to do the operation in place